# Airflow on_failure_callback function is not being triggered if task fails but the DAG is successful

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have set the `on_failure_callback` function at the DAG level as default args and it works as expected when a task fails which causes the DAG to fail too. But it is not being triggered  when a task fails but the DAG is successful.

Any idea why the callback won't be triggered when task fails but DAG is successful? I had the impression that since I set the callback on DAG level, it will trickle down to all tasks and automatically trigger the callback when a task fails.